# Meteor local storage on Samsung tablet not working

Tags: meteor

I have a tablet SM-T211 with android 4.2, when I deploy my app to meteor.com it works fine in Chrome on my desktop but on the tablet all my collections are empty. Is there some setting I need to use on the tablet to make this work?

EDIT:
OK, more tests reveal even weirder stuff:
 - Using Chrome my test app works using my local server, and meteor.com
 - Using the built-in browser it works using my local server, but using meteor.com fails with the Websockets error.

The code is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dbrfuwbpyo1hgv7/test.tar.gz
the meteor site is lstest.meteor.com

Comment: Can you check the tablet's JavaScript console for errors? [Here's one way](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/android-browsers-aboutdebug-what-do-those-settings-do) to do it, and [here's a nicer way](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging) to do it that takes a little more set-up.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first debugging method is for the built-in Android browser, while the second method is for Chrome for Android.

Comment: Thanks Cuberto, I see now that Chrome on the device is working fine, it is the built-in browser that gives the problem. ONce my page loads, I get a link at the top for 'JavaScript Console', when I open that all goes well until my page loads then I see a lot of errors 'Websocket is closed before the connection is established'

Comment: Let me better explain the steps: The page loads, I see doc.ready is fine, alerts in my template handler indicate that there are no records in my collection, I get template.rendered ok, my page looks fine but no data fields are populated.  It is only after all of this that I start getting the Websocket error (about 1 every 10 seconds)

Comment: What version of Meteor is your app using? Can you reproduce the issue with a minimal app? For example, run `meteor create --example leaderboard` and deploy that.

Comment: By the way, that all sounds normal. Without routing Meteor will normally render the body before it receives DDP updates to fill the minimongo database. What isn't normal is that SockJS should be falling back to the backup implementation once it sees WebSockets is unavailable.

Comment: I am using meteor 7.0.1, other comments in my edit above

Comment: Could you try using `https://` instead? Perhaps your ISP uses bytemobile as a proxy using https disallows altering the requests

Comment: I'm using the same Wi-Fi connection for my desktop (which works fine), and the mobile device so the ISP is the same for both. I have narrowed the issue down to the combination of the builtin browser and hosting at meteor.com. Can anyone else with an android device verify that the test site above is ok only with Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what's happening but it could be due to WebSocket support

- CanIUse states, [WebSockets aren't supported in Android Browser prior to 4.4.](http://caniuse.com/websockets)
- The built-in browser/webview is [based on Chromium since 4.4](https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview), which should explain the first point.

Other possibilities (some might be wild):

- Firewall. Not sure how it could pick out your device, but it's worth a try.
- It could also be the version of the packages you have. Try updating all of them, or check for issues with their recent builds. I once used IronRouter and an update broke my code due to API changes.
- It could be that your browser is using an older version of a certain file. Disable your cache when doing development, or at least clear them. Even better, develop in private/incognito mode.
- Check the meteor on the server. They could be using an older, much stable version than the one they are releasing. That solved this issue for [this guy](http://christian-fei.com/solution-websocket-is-closed-before-the-connection-is-established/) (but on Nginx). Make sure the server and local versions match.
- Your device could be in a "data capping mode". Built-in apps generally respect device settings, and third-party devices sometimes don't (especially brightness, rotation etc.) which could explain how Chrome can get through when the built-in browser can't. Be sure to disable any limiters, like power saving, data capping, smart wi-fi etc.
- I do notice that WebSockets have different protocol, and the CanIUse website does mention insecure, older protocols. It could be that the built-in browser is using an older protocol which doesn't prompt an XHR fallback, but the server rejects it. Wild, but a hunch.

Comment: Shouldn't SockJS be emulating WebSockets though? It should still work in environments that don't support WebSockets.

Comment: @Joseph-the-dreamer, it would fall back to XHR. Typically on mobiles websockets does not always work either, some large carriers use bytemobile and this doesn't support websockets.

Comment: @Akshat, do you know if the app bundle gets sent to the client via SockJS?

Comment: @Cuberto the bundle is set via a seperate js file, with the css typically being inline in the html file. The sockjs bit connects after the bundle is fully received. The websockets error sounds like the ISP is using bytemobile. It might go away while using https

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may be using a proxy that disallows websockets like my isp does. While you do see this error it just means the client falls back to XHR. Particularly if you're using some kind of 3G/LTE/wireless connection.

This may be why it works locally but not on meteor deploy hosting.

This is not really an issue, to fall back to XHR the client needs to know websocket has failed.

If you try using https://lstest.meteor.com (with the `https://`) instead you may avoid this problem (since SSL cannot be altered by proxies)

If you want you could add the `force-ssl` package to make everyone use SSL and avoid this problem - if the https:// works.

Comment: Thanks @Akshat, I don't know if my comments above were hidden but:  
I'm using the same Wi-Fi connection for my desktop (which works fine), and the mobile device so the ISP is the same for both. I have narrowed the issue down to the combination of the builtin browser and hosting at meteor.com. Can anyone else with an android device verify that the test site above is ok only with Chrome?          I have tried with https and I get the same results

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the suggestions above (thank you) and no joy. After noticing today that meteor 7.1 has been released, I upgraded my project from 7.0 to 7.1 and it is now working.

There is definitely something weird in 7.0 with the default Android browser, I confirmed that collections were not working on two different devices, 3 different networks (wifi and 3G), on two different meteor.com sites.

Comment: I actually still have this issue - am not sure how I deemed it to be working on meteor 7.1.1 but I have upgraded to 7.1.2 and still the collections don't work with the default browser when using remotely hosted sites.